# Installing Nvidia 770 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, 13.10

I can't get my brand new NVIDIA 770 working on my ubuntu 13.10,
 I had it working perfectly on my 13.04 until my HDD crashed. 
Now it wont work under my 13.04 liveCD or when I upgrade to 13.10.

I need to connect it to my built in Intel HD4000
How do I get the drivers to have the correct resolution, when I use it on my Hisense monitor.

And how do I safely and properly install my NVIDIA drivers, because each time it fails so I reformat the HDD and try again.

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

ok, sounds like you might need "bumblebee" https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee   also check this link  http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

Either use Nvidia or Nouveau though, not both. With bumblebee you have the choice of switching back and forth between both your gfx cards.  :)
Also for Linux, make sure in the BIOS you have disabled UEFI and secure boot/fast boot. You want it on Legacy.